# Selectively prune docker images by tag

Tags: docker

If there are multiple image tags for a used image, `docker image prune -a` will keep the alphabetically last tag. Please see a reproducible example at the bottom.

Is there a way to influence which tags will be kept? Ideally, I would like `docker image prune -a` to keep all image-tag combinations that are in use (in use includes stopped containers).

Reproducible example (careful as it will delete images from your docker system):

```
# docker image prune -a keeps hellow-world:x

docker pull hello-world
docker tag hello-world:latest hello-world:x
docker tag hello-world:latest hello-world:a
docker run hello-world:x
docker run hello-world:a
docker image prune -a
```

```
# Reset

docker system prune -a
```

```
# docker image prune -a keeps hellow-world:z

docker pull hello-world
docker tag hello-world:latest hello-world:x
docker tag hello-world:latest hello-world:z
docker run hello-world:x
docker run hello-world:z
docker image prune -a
```

Comment: I think this question relates to the open issue in the moby project regarding 'docker image prune/rm removes in-use docker tags' https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36295

Comment: Yes, the image remains but the image-tag combination is deleted even for a running container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do it natively with the `docker` cli, but a combination of `awk`/`sed` can help.

```bash
~# docker pull hello-world
~# docker tag hello-world:latest hello-world:x
~# docker tag hello-world:latest hello-world:z
~# docker run hello-world:x
~# docker run hello-world:z
```

Instead of using `prune`, we'll generate the list of images and then send to `docker rmi` instead:

```bash
~# docker ps -a --format '{{.Image}}' > ps_images
~# cat ps_images
hello-world:z
hello-world:x

~# docker images --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}' | sort -r
hello-world:z
hello-world:x
hello-world:latest
```

Those are the images as they might be pruned, where (due to the `sort -r`) `hello-world:z` should be retained since it is the lexicographically last image for `hello-world`. If we filter out images found in the preceding `docker ps -a` command, we should preserve both `:z` and `:x`, which in this case means removing `:latest`.

```bash
~# docker images --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}' | sort -r \
  | awk -F: '{arr[$1]++;print(arr[$1],$1 ":" $2);}' \
  | sed -nE 's/^([^1] |1[^ ]+ )(.*)/\2/gp' | grep -f ps_images -v
hello-world:latest
```

We can send this directly to `docker rmi`:

```bash
~# docker images --format '{{.Repository}}:{{.Tag}}' | sort -r \
  | awk -F: '{arr[$1]++;print(arr[$1],$1 ":" $2);}' \
  | sed -nE 's/^([^1] |1[^ ]+ )(.*)/\2/gp' | grep -f ps_images -v \
  | xargs docker rmi
Untagged: hello-world:latest
~# docker images
REPOSITORY    TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
hello-world   x         feb5d9fea6a5   15 months ago   13.3kB
hello-world   z         feb5d9fea6a5   15 months ago   13.3kB
```

Walk-through:

- `sort -r` orders them with latest-first
- `awk ...` numbers them by the first component of the image name, where its output is

  ```
  1 hello-world:z
  2 hello-world:x
  3 hello-world:latest
  ```
- `sed ...` removes the `1`  lines
- `grep ...` removes images that we discovered from `docker ps -a` in the first code block (the `-v` is inverting the match)
- `xargs ...` sends the output lines (`hello-world:latest` in this case) as individual arguments to `docker rmi`